# Load CSV data into HTML and step through rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a CSV file which is always in the following format

```
COL A   |   COL B        |  COL C      |
---------------------------------------
Email   |   First Name   |   Last Name |
```

So on each row, column A contains the email, column B the first name and column C the last name.

What I am attempting to do is read this CSV file and inject some of the data within a modal I am displaying.  At the moment I have come up with the following

```
$(function () {
    $("#preview-btn").bind("click", function () {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s\S_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
        if (regex.test($("#fileOne").val().toLowerCase())) {
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                        var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                        $('#myModal .modal-body').load('./emailTemplate.html', function(){
                            $(this).find("#fName").append(cells[1]);
                            $(this).find("#lName").append(cells[2]);
                        });
                    }

                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                };
                reader.readAsText($("#fileOne")[0].files[0]);
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
        }
    });
});
```

So the function splits the rows within the CSV, loads a HTML template, and injects the first name and last name into the html for row 1.

So the above works fine.  The problem I am having is that within my model I have the following buttons

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-prev">Prev</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-next">Next</button>
```

What I am trying to do is if Next is clicked, to display the data from the next row, opposite for the Prev button.  I am having issues integrating these 2 button events with the above.

With what I currently have in place, how can I step through the rows within the CSV?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pseudo simple of how to manage the next/prev buttons.

The key is to declare a pointer for the current row. So when user clicks `next` the pointer will "move" to next (e.g. `0` to `1` etc.) than call the function which parse the row and display it.

If something is not clear, let me know.

```js
var current = 0;
var rows = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
console.log(rows);

function applyRow() {
  console.log(rows[current]);
  var cells = rows[current].split(",");
  $("#fName").html(cells[0]);
  $("#lName").html(cells[1]);
}
applyRow();

$('.btn-next').click(function(){
  current++;
  applyRow();
});

$('.btn-prev').click(function(){
  current--;
  applyRow();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>
  john,doe
  john1,doe1
  john2,doe2
</textarea>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="fName"></td>
    <td id="lName"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-prev">Prev</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-next">Next</button>
```

Comment: How would I amend this to handle a CSV file?

Comment: Just like you did, just replace `$('textarea').val()` with `e.target.result`

Comment: Wouldnt that need to be done in the preview-btn event though?  What I am trying to do now is move that into its own function.

Comment: `preview-btn` -> `btn-prev`? Also, `move that into its own function` do you mean to create function `prevClick` for example and call it when user click on `btn-prev`?

Comment: Exactly.  What I am trying to do is when the preview button is clicked, to display the first row of data.  Then when next and prev are clicked, display the appropiate data.  I have tried with your example but having difficulties integrating the CSV reading.

Comment: Why? once you store the rows in the variable `rows` you will not deal with the csv file again (You store its data in `rows`).

Comment: I am having trouble getting the rows variable out of the event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127192/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-kate-hudson).

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you code right, you only load the first row

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) { ... }
```

Just load all rows this way  and insert them into a table. With CSS you hide all rows of this table by default. When loading is done set a global variable `var i=1`. Add a function:

```
function updateRows(){
  $('#tableId tr').hide()`;
  $('#tableId tr:nth-child(i)').show()`;
}
```

And you buttons manipulate the `i` and then call `updateRows()`